# Ajax code is not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get all content of two.html in onw.html page by using ajax but don't knw its not working in short in have to develop one page application n url should not load below in have posted my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Check browser support
            function demo()
            {
                var name=document.getElementById('dd').value;

                if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    // Store
                    localStorage.setItem("lastname", name);
                    // Retrieve
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "two.html",  
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#result").html(result);
                    }});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <input id="dd" type="text" onblur="demo()" >
        <br/>
        <button>two</button>
        <br/>
        write something & click on link it will redirect to another page.
        close this page and open three.html page.

        <br/>
        <img src="1.png" alt="da" style="width:150px;height:150px"></img>
    </body>
```

## two.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body id="body">

  <div id="result"></div>
  <label>Second Page</label>
  <script>
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
     } else {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does  not support Web Storage...";
    }
   </script>
   <img src="2.gif" alt="da" style="width:150px;height:150px"></img>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: See what is the error in the `error` callback within the `ajax`

Comment: what result are you getting? Is it success or not?

Comment: i have given click event on button and ajax function will call from click event but its shows nothing

Comment: can you see any error in your console?

Comment: In chrome, open the console, click the network tab at the top, find the file you're calling to in the left menu and click it, then in the right menu click response, what is listed there? Hre's an image: http://prntscr.com/8pcps1

Comment: yes--error-->XMLHttpRequest cannot load .........Desktop/example/two.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Also, add `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}` to your ajax call to show you if there are any errors

Comment: Are you running that file from your local machine?

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes sir...

Comment: Is `two.html` a static file whose contents you just want to include, or is the intent of your actual code to pass some values to `two.html` and get some dynamic content?

Comment: both files are static i want retrieve all content of two.html into one.html  without loading page n changing url

Comment: If you only want for test... kill all chrome process and start over with --disable-web-security

Comment: @DanyelDarkcloud but of course, remember to set it back after testing locally :)

Comment: can help out how to kill all process in chrome

Comment: For windows... ```taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T```  For linux ```killall chrome``` or ```killall Chrome```

Comment: Refer this  https://github.com/global-source/javascript_ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome's internal settings are blocking your request because you are not using a supported scheme ie (http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource).

Simply put, you are running the file from your desktop so the file address starts with `file://` and not `http://` or `https://`

You need to run the file from a server setup as your `localhost` or upload the files to a remote server.

you could also simplify your code a touch with the shorthand version [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
             $.get( "two.html", function( result ) {
                  $( "#result" ).html( result );
              });
      });
});
```

Apparently, you can also [set a flag in chrome to override the scheme requirement](https://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Browser+settings+to+support+local+Ajax+calls), but it would be much preferred to just run the files on a server with the correct scheme, and if you do change the flag, be sure to revert it when you're done testing locally, its there for a reason after all.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that if I want the events and javascript to be loaded from ajax, I must parse the result using the .HTML() method on jquery

Answer (score -2):

On your console i can see many errors.

1. you are **trying to make ajax call without localhost** or **without any server** here.
2. you **not mention** its **mime-type: "text/html"** here.

so 1st you need to know ajax.
**Ajax** is not work without **http** or **https** url. so for that you **must** need to **start localhost or setup any webserver**.

and if you want to load your **other html file content** on **your current html page** then you can use

```
$("#results").load("test.html");
```

but it will **works only firefox browser not work on chrome**. because **chrome-security flag** is not allowed you to load files on web browser from your local file system.
if you want it works on chrome also you have two options.

1. you can make your application as an chrome extention.
2. first you can setup any local server and start localhost and copy your files in www or webapp directory and then try for Ajax.

try this if you have setup 2nd step.

```
$("button").click(function(){
     /* you can make ajax by 2 ways 1st ways this which used traditionally */
     $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "two.html",
        mimeType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        });
     /* 2nd Ajax type is...*/
   // $("#result").load("two.html");
  });
```

if you have **wamp** server then copy your all files and paste on this direcory
**"C:\Program Files\wamp\www\"** and

start your localhost.

open browser and type localhost

and select your base html file. and then click the button it will works.

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: is it necessary to mention mime-type: "text/html"

Comment: i have tried your way but ts not working still above solution is working

Comment: because, 2nd One just load your HTML File Content for more info please follow jQuery Official site Refrence 1st One: "**http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/**" and 2nd One : "**http://api.jquery.com/load/**"